# Inserting a GUID to each existing row

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

question concerning SQL Server:

I have added a column with type uid to a table with already existing data.

How can I insert a guid in each row of this existing table?

(I mean without reading out the data with a dataadapter, adding a guid for each row and the updating the table [unless there is a method to automatically generate the update command])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it in SQL by running a query against your database. You could use [SQL Server Management Studio.](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=C243A5AE-4BD1-4E3D-94B8-5A0F62BF7796&displaylang=en)

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = newid()
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this would work:

```
   Update mytable 
   Set idcolumn = newid()
```